# Rmd won't knit in RStudio

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, non-ascii-characters

I was running an Rmd script and got this error when I tried to knit in RStudio:

Error in if (isTRUE(opts$get("preview")) && !(nms_chaps[i] %in% input)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Calls:  ... render_cur_session ->  ->  -> split_chapters

I couldn't find this error online, but I finally found what was wrong.
There can be **no letters like é,è,à** in the text blocks of rmd!

Comment: You have found a solution. What is your question? A [mre] might be helpful as well.

Comment: My apologies, I'm new and I found the answer myself. It is solved, but I wanted to help people that might experience the same error. What is the common practice to do this kind of thing here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: It is perfectly ok to provide an answer to your own question. You should write them separately, though. And both parts should follow the usual rules for good questions and answers.